# Creating recurring events in a single table design

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there a good way to design recurring events (datetime) in DynamoDB?

In a relational database, this can be done using a recursive method.

The only way I can think of right now is to create a record for each event out to some far future date.

Edit:

The question was too vague so I am updating it for clarity. What I am referring to is a Recurrence Rule from [rfc5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.10) Internet Calendaring and Scheduling Core Object Specification
(iCalendar)
Something like what this would create

```
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO;COUNT=X
```

I am just wondering what other people have done in DynamoDB to handle the Recurrence Rule in their calendaring.

Comment: What's the use case? [EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html) is the go-to AWS service for raising scheduled events.  A typical AWS serverless pattern is to have EventBridge periodically trigger a Lambda function.  A Lambda can perform arbitrary tasks like persisting a record to a DynamoDB table.

Comment: My apologies for the vaugness. Let me edit the question.